# Pycharm selenium how to open actual webbroswer window (LINUX)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver

APOLOGISE FOR FIRST POST, I AM NEW TO STACK OVERFLOW...GREATLY APPRECICIATE THE HELP...
I can get it to run without opening the actual window, I want to see the actual page it opens though...
I have..
-Imported os
-Made sure webdriver is up to date and matches current version
-is on path..(absolute and relative, even put driver in the same file

- tried Chrome and Firefox
- checked chown is me and is executable
  -it will open from separate terminal instance when I type chromedriver.
  -'which chromedriver' shows /usr/bin/chromedriver (and I used that as path.
  I have a very new linux system running Ubuntu (POPos)
  ALL UPDATED AND UPGRADED.
  I don't know what is wrong...

from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless') # Remove this if you want a selenium controlled browser window
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'
options.add_argument('user-agent={0}'.format(user_agent))

preferences = {
        "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
        "download.default_directory": os.getcwd() + os.path.sep,
        "directory_upgrade": True
} # My own set of preferences, use what you want
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', preferences)

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/home/wprice/PycharmProjects/sele/chromedriver-Linux64", options=options) # Since I am using Windows
driver.get("HTTPS://GOOGLE.COM")
time.sleep(20)
driver.save_screenshot("test.png")
```

```
ERRORS:

    /home/wprice/PycharmProjects/sele/bin/python /home/wprice/PycharmProjects/sele/sele.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/wprice/PycharmProjects/sele/sele.py", line 18, in <module>
        driver = webdriver.Chrome("/home/wprice/PycharmProjects/sele/chromedriver-Linux64", options=options) # Since I am using Windows
      File "/home/wprice/PycharmProjects/sele/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
        self.service.start()
      File "/home/wprice/PycharmProjects/sele/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
        self.assert_process_still_running()
      File "/home/wprice/PycharmProjects/sele/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
        raise WebDriverException(
    selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /home/wprice/PycharmProjects/sele/chromedriver-Linux64 unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

Comment: Please add the code you are executing.

Comment: Please add the error stack trace you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have your code / stack trace, so I am guessing it's probably one of the following issues I can think of at the moment::

1. Your editor is unable to find the correct web driver path
2. Your Chrome web driver version doesn't  match with the installed chrome version
3. Error in initializing the web drivers

So, based on that you can try this code, just replace the variables with the right values and it should probably work

```py
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless') # Remove this if you want a selenium controlled browser window
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'
options.add_argument('user-agent={0}'.format(user_agent))

preferences = {
        "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
        "download.default_directory": os.getcwd() + os.path.sep,
        "directory_upgrade": True
} # My own set of preferences, use what you want
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', preferences)

driver = webdriver.Chrome("CHROMEDRIVER.EXE_ABSOLUTE_PATH", options=options) # Since I am using Windows
driver.get("WEBSITE_TO_SCRAPE")
time.sleep(20)
driver.save_screenshot("test.png")
```